# awk change date format from the log file

Tags: date, awk, format

I want to change the date format taken from log file as follows using awk. Can anyone help me on this?

INPUT:

```
Feb 29 03:32:02 localhost.localdomain haproxy[12722]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:46141 [29/Feb/2016:03:32:02.460] loadbalancer 0/0/0/23/23 304 197 - - --VN 29/2/0/0/0 0/0 {Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; ALE-L21 Build/HuaweiALE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36} "GET xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1"
Feb 29 03:32:02 localhost.localdomain haproxy[12722]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:46141 [29/Feb/2016:03:32:02.460] loadbalancer 0/0/0/23/23 304 197 - - --VN 29/2/0/0/0 0/0 {Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; ALE-L21 Build/HuaweiALE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36} "GET xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1"
```

Expected Output:

```
2016-02-29 03:32:02 localhost.localdomain haproxy[12722]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:46141 [29/Feb/2016:03:32:02.460] loadbalancer 0/0/0/23/23 304 197 - - --VN 29/2/0/0/0 0/0 {Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; ALE-L21 Build/HuaweiALE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36} "GET xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1"
2016-02-29 03:32:02 localhost.localdomain haproxy[12722]: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:46141 [29/Feb/2016:03:32:02.460] loadbalancer 0/0/0/23/23 304 197 - - --VN 29/2/0/0/0 0/0 {Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.1; ALE-L21 Build/HuaweiALE-L21) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/37.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36} "GET xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx HTTP/1.1"
```

===============================================================
Command used (wrong syntax):

```
# awk '
{
logdate=$1" "$2" "$3;
changedate="date -d "'"logdate"'" +\"%Y-%m-%d %T\"";
changedate | getline var;
gsub (logdate,var);
print var;`enter code here`
}' test.log
```

Error output:

```
date: extra operand â€˜03:32:02â€™
Try 'date --help' for more information.

date: extra operand â€˜03:32:02â€™
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Morton for formatting the query...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't *need* to use awk, a simple shell loop will work:

```
while read mon day rest; do
  printf "%s %s\n" "$(date -d "$mon $day" +%F)" "$rest"
done < file.log
```

If you must use awk, it's not really necessary to call out to date for each line:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec", m)
        for (i=1; i <= 12; i++) mon[m[i]] = i
    } 
    { 
        $1 = sprintf("2016-%02d", mon[$1])
        sub(/ /,"-")
        print
    }
' file.log
```